# Send Email When Cell Value Changes from Formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I'm trying to send an email using the script below.

```
function onChange(e)
{
  sendNotification2(e);
}
function sendNotification2(e){
if(e.range.getColumn()==49 && e.value=='Yes'){
 var recipients = "myemail@GMAIL.COM";
 var subject = "Email Subject Line";
  var valColF =e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.getRow(),6).getValue();
  var valColAD =e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.getRow(),30).getValue();
  var body = "TEST" +valColF+ " " +valColAD;
 GmailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body)
 }
}
```

but I am getting an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getColumn' of undefined
at sendNotification2(Danger Zone:6:12)
at onChange(Danger Zone:3:3)"

I had the script to run from OnEdit (installable) and there were no errors, however the email wouldn't send I believe because OnEdit is only triggered by actual edits, not changes in values from formulas. Changing to OnChange unfortunately gets me just as far.

I'm trying to have an email sent when a value drops below 40% in column AD on a sheet called Agent Rankings, the value is changed by formula.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the value being watched changed by a script or by a human?

Comment: A combination of JSON import, form submissions and manual updates will change the formula value, so I guess both?

Comment: Please edit your post and add a sample editable and open sheet, with which we can reproduce your question, and help you find a solution. Since you are a new user, I recommend reading [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Have you tried using a time-based trigger to check the value of the cell? Maybe once every X minutes per your requirement?